# creating a list using android xml and java

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-xml

I got a list from the web (link is [here](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) )

where it uses two xml layouts to create a list, the first xml is just the background where the second xml is going to be displayed as buttons in a list.

what I am trying to do is have that same list but add a tittle or a picture title at the top, i've been playing around with the list but i cant get it to work, the only way i can think to make this happen is somehow moving the position in which the second xml is displayed and have the top part to add whatever i like.

Thank you for the help and ideas to make this work!

[EDIT] code snippet...
First XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_weight="1"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:divider="#000000"
android:scrollingCache="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Second XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#AA010101"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="1px"
android:layout_height="1px"
android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/img"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY" />
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/title" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="18dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img" 
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the XML file containing the `<ListView>`, by adding whatever you want before (most probably a `TextView` with a Compound Drawable). So that what you called the "background" looks more like this:

Main layout should host a `<TextView>` (+eventuall a Compound Image) + a `<ListView>`.

Secondary layout should host the content of each of your list item. If you have a `<ListView>` in each XML layout, it means you will have a list of lists... I don't know much about your list and app, and do not know what information you would like to display in each list item (e.g. ContactName, CalendarDate, Cities... whatever). But there are very few chances that you need a ListView in both of them.

mainListLayout.xml

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”utf-8″?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”
    android:orientation=”vertical”
    android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
    android:layout_height=”fill_parent”>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="text to replace image"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/reference"
        android:text="Title of the list"/>

    <ListView
        android:id=”@android:id/list”
        android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
        android:layout_height=”wrap_content” />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Drawable can obviously be on the Right, Top or Bottom, and not only on the Left. You might also like to have a look at `android:drawablePadding="@dimen/xxx` to add some extra space between text/title and the image. Drawable has to be one of your ic_* png files from res/drawable (eventually -hdpi, -mdpi and so on)

itemLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
android:contentDescription="@string/ItemIcon"
android:layout_width="000"
android:layout_height="000"
android:src="@drawable/ic_icone"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/ItemDescription"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:text="ItemDescription" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i tried that but i get a list of items and each item has the title. I think the way the list i got is set up is that the first xml that has only a listview is like a background and the second xml with the linearlayout is to create each list item

Comment: sorry, not sure I get your point. do you WANT a title+image to each and every list item? or do you GET a title+image to each and every list item with what you've done?

Comment: sorry for not explaining it good! I get a title+image to each list item with what i did but i dont want that, i want the list to stay the way it but i just wanted to add a title on top of the list, for example i have a list of fruits and at the top i wanted to say fruits

Comment: OK that's what I had understood at first. Can you please post your onCreate(bundle) function and your 2 xml files? If you have developped a specific ListAdapter, please paste it too!

Comment: yea sure here is the first xml:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:divider="#000000"
    android:scrollingCache="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

Comment: here is the Second one:   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#AA010101"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >    
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_height="1px" 
    android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

Comment: <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   
    <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/img"
 android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />

Comment: <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="18dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
 android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" />   

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: the oncreate and the rest of the code is on the link that i provided above, its too big to fit in here

Comment: Main layout should host a `TextView` + a `ListView`. Secondary layout hosts the content of each of your list item. If you have a `ListView` in each XML layout, it means you will have a list of lists... I know very few about your list, and do not know what information you would like to display in each list item (e.g. ContactName, CalendarDate, Cities... whatever). But there are very few chances that you need a `ListView` in both of them. I have updated my first answer with an item layout example.